# Creating the difference of two numbers without a sign in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cell-format

I am trying to create a sheet that if I input two numbers in two separate cells, I can have a third cell that has the difference of the two numbers.  The catch is I don't want a negative sign in it at any point.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
A1: 200
B1: 203
C1: 3
```

For perspective this is for bodyweight tracking for a football team.  We take bodyweights on Mondays(`A1`) and Wednesdays(`B1`).  Since bodyweights are always changing there is a chance they might have gained/lost/stayed the same with weight, which is why I just cant use a simple subtraction formula.

Comment: The athletes may have gained or lost weight, and all you care about is the *amount* of change, and not the direction?  Over the course of three measurements, Sam might have gone 200 → 203 → 208 while Tom went 200 → 203 → 198, and *all you care about* is that they both changed 3 between the first two measurements and 5 between the last two? That doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the subtraction into the ABS() function, any negative signs will be removed.

```
=ABS(A1-B1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use square root of the squared number.

```
=SQRT((N)^2)
```

That way, even if 'N' is negative, you still have it's positive value.

Just replace 'N' with the needed columns (like A1-A2).